# When using mozc to input Japanese, it's using the last selected keyboard layout to input romaji - can I fix which one it uses?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus, japanese

I'm setting up Ubuntu to be able to input in three keyboard layouts:

1. English (US)
2. German
3. Japanese (Mozc)(IBus)

What I'm finding is if I switch from English to Japanese directly, then romaji is input with a QWERTY keyboard, but if I switch to German first, and then to Japanese, the romaji is input with German's QWERTZ keyboard.

In other words, mozc is just using whichever keyboard layout I had selected just before switching to it for entering romaji.

I'd like if I could fix it to one (preferably English US) regardless of which keyboard I was using last. If that means an alternative to mozc, I'm open to that too. In the meantime I can work around it as long as I remember to switch directly from English to Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

First click on this Mozc icon and bring

[image]

this window and click on the red arrow, preference button,

[image]

Pull-down the menu from Input Method Default to your favorite.

Comment: Thanks. Most of that menu was missing for me, but now that I know what the option's name was, I was able to search more effectively, and found that I had to switch from IBus to fcitx in the Language Support menu in order for those options to appear. After that I was able to follow your advice and get it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If it is desired to keep IBus instead of switching to fcitx, the file `/usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml` can be edited as a temporary workaround:

Change `<layout>default</layout>` to `<layout>us</layout>` and restart IBus.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

### Solution 1

[Change the `layout` from ibus-mozc.xml file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179859/1076973).

### Solution 2

Edit/import the [romaji-hiragana keymap](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/preedit/romanji-hiragana.tsv) from `ibus-mozc` to your keyboard layout.

## How to do (solution 2)

To do that:

1. Click on `Gnome Status` menu (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus` menu (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select `Japanese Mozc` input method.
2. Again, click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings` window.
3. From `Keymap` section > click on `customize` button (second one, from `Romaji table`).
4. Create new entries with your specific keys to binding the romaji-hiragana keys.
5. If messed things up, click on `reset to defaults` button from `Mozc Settings` window.

See the screenshots about [image: how to edit your ibus-mozc]

## Explanation

### IBUS

Every time I switch the language (e.g: english, spanish, etc) from IBUS, the keyboard layout changes.
So the keys are remapped.
But this is an [IBUS comportment](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1943#issuecomment-327703243).
And some users reported [this issue before](https://github.com/google/mozc/issues/408).

### MOZC

Specifically for MOZC, it doesn't change the keyboard layout.
Because Japanese (romaji) can be [inserted/typed/represented by any language](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1943#issuecomment-329963342) (phonetically).

And the most common usage is [to use only one foreign language keyboard layout](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1943#issuecomment-356184920).
So MOZC switch by your_foreign_language to japanese.
It is an one-to-one relation, by default.

## Alternative solutions

### Install another Japanese IMEs

Just install and use another Input Method Engines (IMEs).
MOZC is just one IME (a Japanese IME).
Japanese IMEs from IBUS are: MOZC, anthy, SKK, KKC.

To install these IBUS Japanese IMEs:

- [MOZC](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1943#issuecomment-329963342): `sudo apt install ibus-mozc`.
- [Anthy](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1943#issuecomment-356184920): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`.
- [KKC](https://github.com/ibus/ibus): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`.
- [SKK](https://fcitx-im.org): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.

After install all of them, you can select the desired one by: Click on `Gnome Status` menu (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus` menu (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select your desired (japanese) IME.
You can see at the first screenshot all of them installed (see the green highlight) and showed by IBUS to be selected.

### Install another IMFs

You can install a alternative for [IBUS](https://github.com/ibus/ibus).
IBUS is a type of Input Method Framework (IMF).
It manages different kind of IMEs.

One suggestion is to install FCITX:

- [Fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org): `sudo apt install fcitx`.

  - and you need to install the IMEs for FCITX, like:

    - `sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-kkc`.
    - `sudo apt install fictx-skk`.
- [Ibus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus): `sudo apt install ibus`

A list of IMF can be found in [List of input methods for Unix platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms) and [Linux input method framework brief summary](https://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/).

I think with that information you can manage what can work for your local setup.

Answer (score 0):

### 2021 Solution: User Config

Recent versions of ibus store the layout in the user configuration directory, which is preferable to modifying the installation config as root.

1. **Edit `ibus_config.textproto` in your user configuration directory**, i.e. one of:

- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`
- `$HOME/.config/mozc/ibus_config.textproto`
- `$HOME/.mozc/ibus_config.textproto`

2. **Change the `layout` key to `us`**, i.e.

   ```
   engines {
     name : "mozc-jp"
     longname : "Mozc"
     layout : "default"   <-- change "default" to "us"
   }
   ```
3. **Run `ibus write-cache; ibus restart` to apply changes.**

Credits:

- Thanks ibus team for the super helpful comments inside of `/usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml`.
- Thanks [Daniel T](https://askubuntu.com/users/1004020/daniel-t) for his  [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179859/417592).