# mozc.xml <layout> what are the possible values?

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus, japanese, mozc

My goal is simple: to get the same Kana input layout as Windows on a US English keyboard. By default, the Kana input layout of iBus Mozc is very different from that of Windows.

After reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029522/japanese-mozc-wrong-keyboard-layout), I thought it could be achieved by changing the keyboard layout value. The aforementioned question only showed `default` and `jp`. Mine also had been set to `default`, so I tried `jp`. The result was almost what I wanted, with just one deal-breaker: I cannot type "ろ". I searched Google Image, and found that real Japanese keyboards have a dedicated "ろ" key, which US English keyboard does not have. On Windows, I press the tilde key (the key left to the "1" key) to type "ろ", but with Mozc `jp`, that key just toggled the input mode.

I thought I could try other layouts than `jp`, but after searching Google, I could not find the list of possible values. What are the possible values? Or, specifically, what is the name of a layout that is just like `jp`, but lacks the dedicated "ろ" key? Or, if there is no such layout, is there any way to make the tilde key type "ろ" just like Windows?

Answer (score 1):

[image: comparison US/JP]

Japanese JIS keyboard layout has one key column more, compare to the US layout.
We get ろ on ~ the US keyboard layout, but it usu on the left of Shift_R on JIS layout. Be aware of your keyboard, don't change setting for the OS, unless you have both.

[image: 84 keyboard]

I have another interesting example, the mobile Japanese keyboard likewise 84 keys has some functions on the same key should be used with Fn or other modifier keys, so that Hankaku/Zenkaku key and Tilde key are at the same place (on the left of 1), that gives you strange result, I think.

To fit the Japanese keyboard layout to your particular keyboard layout,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then, still you probably can't type some letters which on the last column of Japanese layout or you need to solve the puzzle which goes where,  If you are using US keyboard layout, you should set the layout to US or default.
Open Imput Method Configuration by System Settings > Text Entry > select Mozc and click 'wrench'
or `im-config`

[image: Input Method configuration]

You can set the toggle key combination here.

[image: Mozc configuration]

You can set what kind of input mode Roman/Kana on Mozc configuration, that is inside of Mozc engine.

Finally,
ろぬふあうえおやゆよわほへ
たていすかんなにらせ゛゜む
ちとしはきくまのりれけ
つさそひこみもねるめ
These are the letters when I pressed the keys from left to right, 1st row to 4th row.
Note: my mother tongue is Japanese, sorry about my strange English. And I hope you get it.

Comment: 恐縮ですが、問題の解決にはなりません。根本的な問題は、USキーボードで、iBus-Mozcの仮名の配置がWindowsと異なることです。`default`にすれば全ての文字を入力することはできますが、すでに手に馴染んでいるWindowsでの配置と異なるため使いにくくなります。`jp`にしたら、"ろ"が入力できなくます。それに、先程気づいたんですが、`jp`ではtildeキーを押して英語モードにしたとき、@や"などの配置が変になるので、結局この`jp`は使えそうではないです。Fcitx-Mozcにはこの問題がなくて、仮名の配置がWindowsと同じですが、Gnome系列ではiBusがdefaultになっていてFcitxが上手くintegrateしない問題がありますので、進退両難です。ローマ字モードを使ったらこんな複雑なことはないですが、仮名入力より遅くて不便ですし。

Comment: ちなみに、USキーボードで、iBus Mozc 仮名モードを使ったら、第一列の配置は、`゛ぬふあうえおやゆよわほほ`, shiftキーを押した場合には`をぬ゛ぁぅぇをぉけゅょろれ`になります。Windowsでは、同じキーボードで`ろぬふあうえおやゆよわほへ`, shiftキーを押した場合には`ろぬふぁぅぇぉゃゅょをーへ`になります。

Comment: The inappropriate design of ibus-mozc should be reported to ibus team, no one can help it essentially here. Or you can use Xfce or Mate desktop and fctix. You can also buy Japanese keyboard, most easy solution to this.

Comment: the image reference was very helpful, I really wish ubuntu would show that when I'm in Japanese mode, I'm otherwise going in blind since I have a US keyboard and otherwise don't know what key output what.

Comment: @Eman, Open Ibus-preferences and check "Show Icon on the System Tray"

Comment: I toggle between japanese & english no problem from the tray, it's more when I'm in the japanese mode show keyboard layout shows me an english keyboard, which is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Eman, I agree. But since I assigned each key for switch into a particular language, Alt_R to English and Ctl_R to Japanese, I don't even look to the indicator. fcitx5-mozc can set a key to activate/deactivate.

Comment: that still doesn't help with knowing what key makes what character.

Comment: @Eman, I was talking about the panel indicator for selected language. Keyboard layout is another issue. Over 90% of Japanese people type phonic input <Romaji> which we can do a for あ and ka  for か.