# Ubuntu MATE anthy: Installed fctix-anthy and enabled it via fctix configurator. But I cannot swich into it

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, input-language, japanese

Today I have installed ubuntu MATE 18.04 and I need to write into 3 language setups: Greek, english and Japaneese. For the japaneese input I use anthy thus I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install fctix anthy fctix-anthy
```

And I configured the fctix to use the anthy:

[image: Anthy Configuration fctix]

I also configured my system to use fctix as default input method as well:

[image: Installed and Used FCTIX]

I also configured the fctix to use alt+shift in order to change Input input method:

[image: Fctix Configuration]

But by pressing, as configured alt+shift does not change into Japanaese-anthy language input at all.

Furthermore I unchecked the option "Enable Hotkey to scroll between Input method" at fctix input as well but for some reason the whole session freezes, making unable to close windows and open other software.

I managed to fix the freeze by completely removing `fctix` support via pressing `alt`+`f1` relogin and type theese command:

```
sudo apt-get purge fctix*
sudo service lightdm restart
```

But now I do not know how to enable anthy either via `ibus` or `fctix`.

Comment: Anthy is an old input method and the window pops up unexpectedly, I guess it's better to use Mozc instead. And your setting "Shift_R" key is the way to change between US, Greek and Japanese(Anthy), the triger shortcut is best that is not reserved, e.g. Alt_R, Suer_R or Control+Space.

Comment: So I need to disable completely the xinput and let fctix to do the job right?

Comment: **sudo apt install fcitx-mozc** and see other references on the AskUbuntu forum, you need fcitx and xinput. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104599/how-do-i-toggle-input-modes-with-mozc?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://askubuntu.com/questions/929793/when-using-mozc-to-input-japanese-its-using-the-last-selected-keyboard-layout?rq=1